# simple maven web project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven

For last few hours I’m trying to set up a simple(create a simple project(skip archetype selection) )maven javeEE project in eclipse with one servlet and one jsp, nothing fancy.  Can someone explain me with pom.xml what dependency should be included, and proper file structure?

I will try to explain how i do it.

I click in eclipse Maven Project and from there I checked create a “`Simple project(skip archetype selection`”. Then I create `WEB-INF` in `src/main/webapp/` inside WEB-INF I create `web.xml`. 
Inside WEB-INF I create `index.jsp`. In `src/main/java/com/test/` I create `TestServlet`.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Pl_Kurs</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

TestServlet.java:

```
 package com.test;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


 @WebServlet("/test")
 public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello servlet");
}

 }
```

pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>WebAppTest</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax</groupId>
          <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
          <version>6.0</version>
       </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: Perhaps if you show us what you've tried, we could point out the problems...

Answer (score 1):

I created a PPT on Getting Started with Maven for a workshop. You can go through this and you'll be cleared about your doubt.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5dpzztnm2lahw8/Maven_Eclipse.pptx

Comment: Thanks for a link.
It works with jps, but when i add a servlet(class) to src/main/java and dependency for maven.
Gives me this error:
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Comment: Then i guess , there might be some problem with the version of the dependency you are including in.

Comment: Try going with webapp archetype as explained in the ppt. You'll get your desired structure.